# Fabric.js: custom rotation point

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have found a workaround [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mlukman/5ce3np9h/4/) (see code below), but I wonder if Fabric has built-in support to set the rotation point of an object to a specific place.

```
function rotateObject(fabObj, angleRadian, pivotX, pivotY) {
  ty = pivotY - fabObj.height / 2.0;
  tx = pivotX - fabObj.width / 2.0;
  if (angleRadian >= Math.PI * 2) {
    angleRadian -= Math.PI * 2;
  }
  angle2 = Math.atan2(ty, tx);
  angle3 = (2 * angle2 + angleRadian - Math.PI) / 2.0;
  pdist_sq = tx * tx + ty * ty;
  disp = Math.sqrt(2 * pdist_sq * (1 - Math.cos(angleRadian)));
  fabObj.set({transformMatrix:[
    Math.cos(angleRadian),
    Math.sin(angleRadian),
    -Math.sin(angleRadian),
    Math.cos(angleRadian),
    disp * Math.cos(angle3),
    disp * Math.sin(angle3)
  ]});
}
```

Comment: Since there is no built-in support, probably the best way (a better way than described above) of dealing with this is to put your object inside a group, adjust its position relative to the center point of the group, and rotate the group.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built in method.

By default mouse rotation on fabricjs is around the center point.

If you deactivate centeredRotation on objects, setting it to false:

`fabric.Object.prototype.centeredRotation = false`

the object will start to rotate around the originX and originY position.

Then you can set for each object a specific originX and originY, that can be numeric and represent any point inside the object ( with values ranging from 0 to 1 ) i m not even sure if you can do it with points outside the object.

At that point the object rotates around that point, just setting the angle property to a desired angle.

Consider that now also position is relative to that origin.

As a side not, do not set transformMatrix of an object. is unsupported and will give you weird controls in case of interactivity with controls.

In your specific example, once found the matrix:

```
var matrix = [
  Math.cos(angleRadian),
  Math.sin(angleRadian),
  -Math.sin(angleRadian),
  Math.cos(angleRadian),
  disp * Math.cos(angle3),
  disp * Math.sin(angle3)
];

var options = fabric.util.qrDecompose(matrix);

object.set(options);
object.setPositionByOrigin({ x: options.translateX, y: options.translateY }, 'center', 'center');
```

this should give you same effect but being supported by fabricjs better.

Comment: I take your advice, but I am not working with interactivity (mouse rotation). The example on jsfiddle does what I want however.

Answer (score 2):

Rotation on fabricjs is around the center point.
This fuction is on developmenting...
but I have implemented to line rotation.
Redrawing line from custom center point to mouse position.
it works well for me.

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO! Can you please add some code examples to your answer for more clarity? Thanks!

Comment: This is my past work https://www.useloom.com/share/b98fec7071234ba8a027dccd9a05bedc
codes for line rotation:
init : {
},
mouseDown : function(c, a, e){
},
mouseUp : function(c, a, e){
},
mouseMove : function(c, a, e){      
var c1 = {
x  : a.LT.l * Math.cos(Math.atan(pr.a)) + a.LT.c2.left,
x1  : (-1)*a.LT.l * Math.cos(Math.atan(pr.a)) + a.LT.c2.left,
y  : a.LT.l * Math.sin(Math.atan(pr.a)) + a.LT.c2.top,
y1  : (-1)*a.LT.l * Math.sin(Math.atan(pr.a)) + a.LT.c2.top,
}   
a.LT.ln.set({ 'x1': lp[0].x, 'y1': lp[0].y, 'x2': lp[1].x, 'y2': lp[1].y };    
c.renderAll();
}
return;

Comment: @ArreMariana: Please be so kind and put the code into your question, my suggested edit of doing so got rejected.